# Is there such a term as "dinner box"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

From my understanding, a *lunch box* is food packed from home to eaten during lunch time either in school or the office.

Is there such a term as *dinner box*? If there is no such term, how can I describe food that is packed from home and is to be eaten during dinner time in school or at the office?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nearest I can think of would be "packed dinner".  Also "packed lunch" would be the more generic term.  A lunch box is, to me, a fairly specific container for a packed lunch.

Comment: The reason we don't say "dinner box" is exactly that it isn't at all common to pack a dinner, as compared to packing a lunch.

Comment: In the area of the North of England that I live in, your midday meal is called dinner and your evening meal is tea. It's still called a lunch box though.

Comment: @Scott: Further south in la-la / lah-de-dah land the adults have lunch in the day and dinner in the evening - but same as yours, our kids get [school dinners, not school lunches](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=school+dinners%2Cschool+lunches&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: In the UK, at least, "lunch box" can be used for both cases.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm lah-de-dah myself, a Kentish native now in Yorkshire! That's what's fuelled my interest in the English language. I think the box has its own name, no matter when the food is consumed, you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes to all the above.  Thinking about times I've done overnight support etc I think I would just say something like "I brought my own dinner/tea" rather than any specific term.

Comment: Thanks Wudang, I think "packed dinner" is consider quite generic term for packing dinner to be consume at dinner time in office / school.

Answer (score 1):

The terms *dinner pail, dinner bucket, lunch box, lunch pail,* and *lunch bucket* all have some [currency, per ngrams,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dinner+box%2Cdinner+pail%2Cdinner+bucket%2Clunch+box%2Clunch+pail%2Clunch+bucket&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but *dinner box* much less so.[image: ngram for 6 lunch/dinner box/pail/bucket]

*Dinner pail* is found in [euphemism for death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expressions_related_to_death) "To hand in one's dinner pail", and in the 1900 [campaign slogan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_slogans) of William McKinley, "Four more years of the full dinner pail".

Comment: +1 for the statistics information about the terms dinner pail, dinner bucket, lunch box, lunch pail, and lunch bucket.